# how to make enum values with | in them

Tags: android, xml, enums, declare-styleable

I declared an android custom view
that has an enum in it

```
   <attr name="ff_type" format="enum">
            <enum name="small" value="1" />
            <enum name="big" value="32" />
            <enum name="medium" value="8288" />

        </attr>
```

how to allow in my xml of the custom view to do  `app:ff_type="small|medium"` ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `flag` rather than `enum`:

```
<attr name="ff_type" format="flag">
    <flag name="small" value="1" />
    <flag name="big" value="32" />
    <flag name="medium" value="8288" />
</attr>
```

Inclusion of `format="flag"` is optional.

`8288` is an odd choice, you're better sticking to powers of `2`. As it stands `8288 = 32 * 259`. Therefore you can't select `medium` without implying `big`.

```
<attr name="ff_type">
    <flag name="small" value="1" />
    <flag name="medium" value="2" />
    <flag name="big" value="4" />
</attr>
```

Then you can optionally add additional values as shortcuts:

```
<attr name="ff_type">
    <flag name="small" value="1" />
    <flag name="medium" value="2" />
    <flag name="big" value="4" />
    <flag name="smallerThanBig" value="3" />
</attr>
```

So here `smallerThanBig` is the same as `small|medium` (but you can use both).

Comment: You are almost correct , instead of format=flag i need to put format=integer and the <flag remains the same
However, now my problem is, the number that returns isnt bitwise or between the values...

Comment: "isnt bitwise or between the values"? What is it then?

Comment: I'd drop the `format` altogether rather than choosing `integer` see if that helps.

Answer (score 0):

`<flag/>`can be multiple,like  gravity="center | left"
but `<enum/>` must be single,like  layout_height="wrap_content"